# SQL select query to select from 3 tables

Tags: sql

I have the following tables and relationships:

T1 -> id1, v1, v2
T2 -> id2, va, vb, vc
T3 -> id1, id2, v

T1 0-to-many T3
T2 0-to-many T3

I want to select *v1, v2, va, vb, vc, v* where *id1* & *id2* exist in *T3*.
What SQL-query will give this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is an `INNER JOIN` since you want only records on `T3` where `ID`s exists on `T1` or `T2`.

```
SELECT  v1, v2, va, vb, vc, v
FROM    T3 INNER JOIN T1 ON T3.id1 = T1.id1
        INNER JOIN T2 ON T3.ID2 = T2.id2
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Yes, of course! (Am doing a quick-&-dirty using sqlite and haven't used SQL in a while) - SO makes me lazy to think, I wonder how many others suffers this same affliction :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this one -

```
SELECT 
      t1.v1
    , t1.v2
    , t2.va
    , t2.vb
    , t2.vc
FROM dbo.T3 t3
JOIN dbo.T2 t2 ON t2.id2 = t3.id2
JOIN dbo.T1 t1 ON t1.id2 = t3.id2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.v1, t1.v2, t2.va, t2.vb, t2.vc, t3.v from T1 t1, T2 t2, T3 t3 where t1.id1=t3.id1 and t3.id2=t2.id2
```